# .Net 4.0 Threadpool in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm currently working on a windows azure project and we are using a command pattern to encapsulate our method calls. Now we are trying to execute the commands in parallel and have control over the number of threads which are created.

First thought: [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) is easy to use and you can set MaxThreads. But as far as i know every Begin* (e.g. BeginInvoke) - method uses the threadpool and so we can't control the number of threads dedicated to our commands.

Today a coworker found this [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) on MSDN, looks better than the ThreadPool, but I have no idea if it works properly.

Are there any other alternatives to the ThreadPool? Experiences with ThreadPool and Windows Azure ?

Comment: I just want to control the maximal number of threads and not the number of threads at runtime, if you thought so.

Comment: The ThreadPool does a very good job of balancing the number of threads outstanding.  You should let it do its job.  The .NET 4.0 Threadpool is even better about it.  If your tasks are long-running tasks, the Threadpool may not be for you (it does better than the previous one did); you'll want to use the Task system, or create and manage the threads yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.Threading.Parallel` - it has parameters that allow you to control the degree of multithreading.

```
var threadOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 };    
Parallel.For(0, 1000, threadOptions, i=>    
{    
    // do stuff...
});
```

So far, I've used this in WorkerRoles without any issues. In web roles this would be a problem though - as IIS also uses the same `ThreadPool` for handling web requests.

It's worth reading up about - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx - and coming soon in C#5 is the new Async framework too (currently in CTP)

Answer (score 3):

You are running Fx 4, that means you can use the TPL and PLINQ. Both are running on top of the (improved) ThreadPool.

So you could start with just running it on the TPL, for example with `Parallel.ForEach()` . The underlying ThreadPool already tries to balance the workload with the number of threads. For (lots of) fairly short tasks this usually works well.

The next step is to add  `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(numCoresTouse)` to either TPL or PLINQ.

Writing/using a Custom (TPL) scheduler seems overkill here.